# Зачем спрашивать алгоритмы сортировки на собеседовании?

Tags: java, сортировка

Интересуюсь в контексте гипотетического собеседования на Junior Java developer. Витает мнение, что о простейших и неэффективных алгоритмах сортировки спрашивают чуть ли не каждый раз.
В моём понимании, правильный ответ заключается в том, что быструю сортировку давно изобрели и встроили везде где только можно, и незачем тратить ценное оплачиваемое работодателем время на реализацию велосипеда. А просто использовать *.sort, что, собственно все и делают.

Вопрос в том, имеет ли право на жизнь такой ответ интервьюеру, либо это всё вздор и даже неюзабельные алгоритмы должен знать и уметь реализовать каждый уважающий себя разработчик?

Comment: Тут на самом деле всё зависит от работадателя. Бывают моменты, когда у тех, кто опрашивает джунов, есть чёткий список вопросов свыше. Но вообще, как мне кажется, лучше не рисковать

Comment: Этот вопрос не соответствует формату SO, т.к. является opinion based вопросом. Проверяя знания базовых алгоритмов и структур данных интервьюверу важно, чтобы вы не просто написали какой-нибудь код, а написали _правильный_, валидный код. Ничего страшного не случится, если вы вдруг забудете тот или иной алгоритм или метод. Начните рассуждать вслух, как именно вы хотите решать задачу. В конце концов, невозможно знать всё, но базовые понятия нужно помнить обязательно.

Comment: @Nikita судя по своему опыту могу сказать, что базовых знаний недостаточно, элементарные алгоритмы сортировки даже джуниор должен уметь понимать, объяснять и реализовывать как минимум на 2 языках

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, считая, что quicksort достаточно. Во-первых, он неустойчив (элементы с равными ключами сортировки могут поменять порядок). Во-вторых, для данных некоторых сортов есть, внезапно, более эффективные алгоритмы.

Comment: @D-side согласитесь, что устойчивость/неустойчивость зависит исключительно от реализации. Это нельзя считать за недостаток алгоритма сортировки.

Comment: @Nikita не зависит. Классический квиксорт нестабилен/неустойчив как алгоритм, в любой реализации. Точка. Модифицированные версии существуют, но формально это другие алгоритмы, и их эффективность, как правило, отстаёт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Была волна в твиттере на тему, что уважаемые разработчики не могут написать какие-то простые вещи и в этом не было ничего позорного. На [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323188/) было обсуждение данной ситуации.

Лично я считаю, что на стандартном собеседовании странно просить реализовать алгоритм на бумаге. Да и спрашивать про внутреннюю реализацию структур данных в джаве - так себе идея. Гораздо эффективней спрашивать про решение прикладной задачи, а затем спрашивать фундаментальное обоснование решения. [Есть хорошая статья про собеседования](https://habrahabr.ru/post/294224/)

Answer (score 4):

*На единственно верный ответ не претендую, но свое мнение выскажу.*

> Зачем спрашивать алгоритмы сортировки на собеседовании?

Затем, чтобы проверить способность алгоритмического мышления интервьюируемого. Знания, как работают различные сортировки не являются достаточным условием, но они, как минимум, является необходимым.

> В моём понимании, правильный ответ заключается в том, что быструю сортировку давно изобрели и встроили везде где только можно, и незачем тратить ценное оплачиваемое работодателем время на реализацию велосипеда. А просто использовать *.sort, что, собственно все и делают.

На практике, разумеется, следует использовать готовые методы (**а если этих готовых методов нет?**), но это не полный ответ. Полный ответ, заключается, собственно, в этой фразе и рассказе о сортировках, дабы продемонстрировать, что Вы знаете, как они работают.

> даже неюзабельные алгоритмы должен знать и уметь реализовать каждый уважающий себя разработчик?

Да, должен знать и должен уметь реализовывать.

**Эти вещи являются фундаментом для более сложных алгоритмических задач.**